# Не знаю,как придумать проверку на не смежность вершин

Tags: c#, графы

```
public void findDisconnectedNodes(int key)//key-это "вершина"
{
    List<int> disnodes = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < vertexes.Count; i++)//vertexes - список вершин
    {
        //neighbours - список смежных вершин с данной вершиной
        for (int j = 0; j < vertexes[i].neighbours.Count; j++)
        {
            //собственно здесь проверка должна быть)
        }
    }
    Console.Write("Nodes: ");
    foreach (var i in disnodes.Distinct())
    {
        Console.Write(i + "," + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: А что именно должен вернуть ваш метод? Список вершин, не смежных с текущей?

Comment: @PashaPash: Исходя из кода, вывести на консоль.

Comment: ну,я просто добавлял в список "несмежных" вершину удовлетворяющую условию.А затем вывожу

Comment: это решается строчкой `var disnodes = vertexes.Except(vertexes.Single(n => n.Key == key).neighbours).ToList()`. Т.е. просто берете все вершины и выбрасываете из них смежные. Или вы что-то другое пытаетесь найти?

Comment: у меня список смежности есть:
1:2,4    
   2:1,3
   3:2,4
   4:1,3,5
   5:4

Т.е. при key=1,должен мне вывести "3,5"
       при key=2,должен вывести "4,5" и т.п.

Comment: vertexes - что это за тип данных? Какие там поля?

Comment: Список на основе моего класса Node,поля name-имя вершины("1","2","3") и neighbours - стринг список который хранит смежные вершины.

Comment: так для начала добавьте все связанные классы типа Node в вопрос. И как вы получаете узел по ключу? Что такое ключ? Индекс в вашем массиве?

Comment: для чего имя вершины? Где оно используется? А чем отличие имени от ключа (кроме типа данных)?

Comment: Кода отвечаете мне, указывайте меня в комментарии вот так @tym32167, так как без этого я не вижу уведомления, что мне ответили

Comment: @tym32167 кинул класс выше. Там всё описано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из всех узлов вам нужен те, которые не равны вашему ключу и у которых в соседях нет вашего ключа

```
public void findDisconnectedNodes(string key, List<Node> vertexes)  {       
    var disnodes = vertexes.Where(x=> x.name != key && !x.neighbours.Contains(key))
                           .Select(x=>x.name).ToArray();    

    Console.Write("Nodes: ");
    foreach (var i in disnodes.Distinct())
    {
        Console.Write(i + "," + " ");
    }
}
```

Но как общая рекомендация - пересмотрите ваши типы данных. Ключи лучше хранить как целые числа, а не строки.

Comment: Это я на всякий случай,если мало ли задания будут не просто с числовыми вершинами)спасибо большое)я правильно понял весь запрос:
"Вершина не равна != введённой вершине и соседи не содержат введённой вершины"?

Comment: @AlexPark правильно. Если вы не уверены в типе ключа, вы можете сделать обобщенный `Node<T>`, но реализация потребует больших усилий

Comment: это да. Но не хотел так заморачиваться) Спасибо большое ещё раз)